# is it possible to define 2 separate route pointing to one resource controller?

Tags: laravel

i am having a challenge with my route. is it possible to define 2 separate route pointing to one resource controller?

```
Route::prefix('artist')->middleware('role:artist')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', 'ArtistController@index');
  Route::get('/dashboard', 'ArtistController@dashboard')->name('artist.dashboard');
  Route::resource('/mp3', 'Mp3Controller');
});

Route::resource('/mp3', 'Mp3Controller');
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: yes, but both routs will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. In this case these URIs will be pointed to the same method:

```
artist/mp3
mp3
```

Run this command to see all the routes generated by your code:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/abc', 'LandingController@index');
Route::get('/xyz', 'LandingController@index');

index(){
    return view('landing')
}
```

both /abc  and /xyz will load the view called "landing"